# All Laravel routes “not found” on nginx

Tags: nginx, laravel, laravel-4

Trying to setup Laravel 4.1 installation on a nginx server (first time) and I'm given "not found" for every Laravel route instead of the view expected. The main page loads fine.

Please note, site can only be accessed by IP which is why I have the filler IP `123.123.123.123` for `server_name`.

etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
listen 80;

user  nginx;

worker_processes 4;

worker_rlimit_nofile 200000;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 4000;

    use epoll;

    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    include  /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

etc/nginx/site-available/mysite.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  123.123.123.123 "";
    access_log  /srv/www/mysite/logs/access.log;
    error_log  /srv/www/mysite/logs/error.log;
    root  /srv/www/mysite/public_html/public;
    rewrite_log  on;
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main buffer=16k;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    #gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript text/x-js;

    open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors on;

    sendfile on;

    tcp_nopush on;

    tcp_nodelay on;

    keepalive_timeout 90;

    keepalive_requests 100000;

    reset_timedout_connection on;

    client_body_timeout 30;

    send_timeout 30;

    # Remove trailing slash to please Laravel routing system.
    if (!-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite  ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # We don't need .ht files with nginx.
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

    # Set header expirations.
    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|jpe?g|JPG|png|svg|woff)$ {
        expires  365d;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should give this: http://daylerees.com/nginx-configuration-for-daylerees-dot-com a look. It might solve your problem.

Comment: Figured it out thanks to that page. Please add your comment as an answer and I will mark as correct. Solution was in mysite.conf to replace `index  index.html index.htm index.php;` with `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;` and put `index  index.php;` after the `root` declaration line.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of some assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should give this: http://daylerees.com/nginx-configuration-for-daylerees-dot-com a look. It might solve your problem.